# D, 1995, 1998, 2001, 2005

Tags: word, knowledge, music

> Red Prysock. 1955, 2002.
>   The Beach Boys, Heart. 1967, 1970, 1972.
>   Walter Egan. 1970, 1978, 2008.
>   Dead Milkmen. 1967, 2010.

For all you dads out there, here's a puzzle for you!
  *What is the name of the item each line refers to?*

> The years do not pertain to the artist, thus periods instead of commas. 
>  The years *do* pertain to t̡͇̥h̵͋̓͊͐͌ȩ̗̭̈́ͦ͊ ̻͚̲͙̘ͦm̪͎̳͇̻̜̫̓̐̓ͤ̏̓o̶̼̫̓̋ḑ̬͓̖̜ͫ̊e͚̭ͪ̏ͣͤ͂̒ͫl̨̥̩̩͇̖̳͐.

To narrow your song search:

> ..... 
>  Smiley Smile. 
>  Little Queen. 
>  The Lost Album. 
>  Dead Lizard in my Backyard.

Hint:

> Manuel, 2009. 
>  *"Guess you're ready"* 
>  *"'Cause I'm waiting for you"* 
>  *"It's gonna be so exciting!"* 
>  *"Got this feeling"* 
>  *"Really deep in my soul"* 
>  *"Let's get out, I wanna go"* 
>  *"Come along, get it on!"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although not a dad, I do enjoy dad-music...

> It's strange that none of the years pertain to the artists, because [Red Prysock's biggest hit, Hand Clappin', came in 1955](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Prysock) and [Walter Egan's biggest hit, Magnet and Steel, came in 1978](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Egan)...

Okay hang on a sec, new answer:

> I think these all refer to classic cars!!

The first one is talking about

> The Ford Thunderbird (developed in 1955, revived in 2002). Hint: Red Prysock's song "What's the Word, Thunderbird".

The second one is talking about

> The Plymouth Barracuda (I think the generations are slightly different on Wikipedia, they're saying 1964, 1967, 1970; although the car was slightly remade in 1972 so it fits with the clue). Hint: Beach Boys' song "Do You Like Worms? (Roll Plymouth Rock)" and Heart's song "Barracuda"

The third one is talking about

> The Dodge Challenger (First Gen released 1970, Second Gen released 1978, Third Gen released 2008). Hint: Walter Egan's song "Challenger".

The fourth one is talking about

> The Chevy Camaro (First Gen released 1967, revived in 2010 -- and a sweet car it is!). Hint: Dead Milkmen's song "Bitchin' Camaro".

The hint is

> The song "Gas Gas Gas" by Manuel (2009), referring to cars!

From OP (thanks very much, @iiiidk!), the title is

> Initial D, relating to Gas Gas Gas. The years are the show's different releases.

Comment: Oh yes, that's some coincidence, huh?  :) No but really, but you're on the right track- keep investigating the songs. And... perhaps "dad" pertains to not just the music?

Comment: perfect! Yes, it seems wikipedia is saying otherwise... but good job :) rot13(naq gur gvgyr vf Vavgvny Q, eryngvat gb Tnf Tnf Tnf. Gur lrnef ner gur fubj'f qvssrerag eryrnfrf.)

Comment: Thanks!! You were definitely right -- once I figured out the significance of 1955 and 2002, the rest fell into place pretty quickly! Great puzzle, I enjoyed both sets of references :)